# What does a S1-GRD Collection contains?

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript

The following code is to filter, clip and select images from the Sentinel-1 GRD Collection in the Google Earth Engine Platform.

When I print the image collection, and set the start and end date of 1 day difference, I get more than 200 images per orbit (descending, ascending). I was expecting one image in the image collection.

```
var polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[10.8393, 50.3165],[10.8465, 50.3165],
                                    [10.8465,50.3213], [10.8393, 50.3213],
                                    [10.8393, 50.3165]]); 

// Centering the map to our target parcel
Map.centerObject(polygon, 17);

// Function to clip image 
function clip_image(image){
  return image.clip(polygon); 
}

// Function to mask image to certain backscatter signal
function update_s1_mask(image) {
          var edge = image.lt(-30.0);
          var maskedImage = image.mask().and(edge.not());
          return image.updateMask(maskedImage);
        }

var start = '2022-04-01';
var end = '2022-04-02'; 
var dateRange = ee.DateRange(start, end); 
     
var s1_collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
                    .filterDate(dateRange)
                    .map(clip_image)
                    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
                    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
                    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('resolution_meters', 10))
                    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
                    .map(update_s1_mask);
                    
var s1_collection_ = s1_collection.select(['VV', 'VH']);

var desc = s1_collection_.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'));
var asc = s1_collection_.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'ASCENDING'));

print(asc);
print('descending tiles ', desc.size());
print('ascending tiles ', asc.size()); 

print(asc.first()); 

Map.addLayer(desc, {min: -25, max: 5}, 'Multi-T Mean DESC', true);

var visParams_1 = {
  color: 'FF0000',
  width: 2,
  fillColor: '1',  // with alpha set for partial transparency
  lineType: 'dotted',
  pointSize: 10,
  pointShape: 'circle'
```

Could someone explain me why do I get for a given location many images for such a short period of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve only the images that intersect a given region, you need to filter the image collection by bounds using [`ee.ImageCollection.filterBounds`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-imagecollection-filterbounds) (short for `ee.ImageCollection.filter(ee.Filter.bounds()`).

```js
var s1_collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
                      .filterDate(dateRange)
                      .filterBounds(polygon) // <-- FILTER BY BOUNDS
                      ...
```

I think that maybe you are using [ee.Image.clip](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-clip) to perform this, but that function is masking pixels by region, not filtering by region. See [this resource](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/faq#what_the_difference_between_eeimageclip_and_eefilterbounds) that describes the difference. As an aside, [it is best to not clip all images in a collection](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#if-you-dont-need-to-clip,-dont-use-clip); only clip collection composites, the final exports, and/or use the `region` parameter whenever possible in reductions and other functions.

Note that when I run your code using `filterBounds`, there are no images. My assumption is that there was no S1 overpass for that region on 2022-04-01.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will take a look at the documentation about filtering by bounds and clip images. And the explanation about why filterBounds doesn't yield any results, was helpful, it avoided me asking this same follow-up point. :)